# Error Uploading CSV to Google Cloud Storage through Cloud SQL API

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have some data in Google Cloud SQL, which I am trying to transfer to Google Cloud Storage using Cloud SQL API(beta) (export) function. For this, I have installed jupyter notebook on google compute engine and I am running the python code (to connect to cloud sql API and export the date to cloud storage in a csv file) on that.

The python code does not throw any error and also there is no error body in API response. However, the API's response says "**u'status': u'PENDING'**" and I see the following error (in logs of Cloud SQL Dashboard) :
**error uploading CSV file to GCS: gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FILE_NAME].csv: Access denied for account [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME]@speckle-umbrella-11.iam.gserviceaccount.com (permission issue?)**

How do I ensure I have all the relevant access for the account (**[SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME]@speckle-umbrella-11.iam.gserviceaccount.com**) ? I am unable to locate this account or give myself access to this .

Answer (score 1):

By default Google Compute Engine instances have read only scope for Google Cloud Storage.

You should confirm that the Google Compute Engine instance scope is set to read/write.

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant the Cloud SQL instance service account access to your bucket. Visit the [export documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting) and click the `GCLOUD (2ND GEN)` tab which will show you the commands you need to use.

The command to grant the service account access to the bucket is

```
gsutil acl ch -u [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS]:W gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```