# What is the "speckle-umbrella" service account associated with Google Cloud SQL instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-iam

On the instance details page of my Google Cloud SQL instance, I see that there's a "Service account" card on the dashboard with a value.  The domain of which includes **speckle-umbrella**.  This account doesn't show up in the IAM settings or any service account lists.  Regarding its purpose, the most I've been able to find is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759815/error-uploading-csv-to-google-cloud-storage-through-cloud-sql-api) but it seems to only deal with granting the account privileges.  A couple of questions:

- What is this account for?
- Why is this account not enumerated with the rest of the service accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud SQL is a managed service and the instances you create and use actually run in a Google-owned project. The service account you mentioned belongs to that project and is used to perform operations in that project.

The relationship between both projects is clearer with some specific use-cases. For example, in the other SO question you linked about exporting data from CloudSQL to Google Cloud Storage, you need to grant access to your bucket to the service account in question since this SA will be used to authenticate the request to GCS.

Another example is when you create a CloudSQL instance with [private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip). The connection through internal IP is made available by actually peering your network in your project with the network in the speckle-umbrella project where your CloudSQL instance resides. You're then able to see that peering in your [Developer Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/peering/list) showing the "speckle-umbrella" project as peered project ID.

Comment: So unlike an owner-generated service account that could be assigned to roles and have key files generated, I shouldn't expect to see these speckle-umbrella accounts listed with other SAs that I create?  After my initial post, I noticed that the speckle-umbrella SA does show up in the ACL for specific storage bucket objects so if it's true that I don't need to worry about these accounts getting unwanted roles assigned to them, then I think I'm good.  I was mainly concerned with the fact that I couldn't see the account listed anywhere but your answer and the ACL definitely shed some light.

Comment: Exactly, you don't have to worry about the permissions for this SA. Technically, you can give it any permissions you want in your project, as any other SA, but it can only be used by Google to run CloudSQL operations related to that specific instance.

Comment: Do we need to create this peer network manually? we have a composer wherein we are interacting with cloud sql